# Mozilla FF scrollbar issue with ember-scrollable addon

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, ember-cli, ember-addon

I've come across this scenario of default scrollbar shows on mozilla firefox with [ember-scrollable](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-scrollable).I've implemented an aside fixed block with 100vh height and added the above mentioned ember addon. it works fine in webkit browsers but in FF itshows its native scrollbar. is there any fix for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue was with `height:100% !important` for the class 'tse-scroll-content' that overrides its dynamically generated height.